# How do you install an application that doesnt have makefile in folder?

Tags: software-installation, python, compiling, install-from-source, source-code

Sometimes I download applications and they don't include a makefile; just a bunch of source code and an executable application. For instance, I downloaded tor but it comes with the application and a folder full of source code. How can I actually install this in my system so I don't need to run it from my downloads folder? Also how do I add it to my taskbar/dock?

Also is there a way to install python programs instead of running them as "sudo python executable.py"?

I know this is possible because some distros like kali have tor pre-installed, but I would like to do this on Ubuntu.

Sorry if I'm not using correct terminology, I'm coming from a mac.

Answer (score 1):

> applications and they don't include a makefile

- That depends on what has provided the author of the program.
- Use the script `autogen.sh` or `configure`
- Read the instructions in `INSTALL`
- Read the instructions in `README`
- Create your own `Makefile`, eg:

  ```
  nano Makefile
  ```

  with the lines below

  ```
  helloworld : helloworld.c
    cc -o helloworld helloworld.c
  ```

  and run `make`

  ```
  make
  ```
- …

---

> install python programs instead of running them as "sudo python
>   executable.py"

- Create a desktop file [ReadMe](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/367165)

---

> some distros like kali have tor pre-installed

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

Comment: some things are provided as a pre-compiled binary as well =0